# How to prevent svcutil processing a type

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I wanted to prevent `svcutil` to process a type in my assembly and have used the `/excludeType:{NameSpace}.{Type}` parameter. This has no effect and the tool process the type and create a error saying `Duplicate contract XmlQualifiedNames are not supported`. Is my assumption correct that this parameter `/et` should prevent processing a type inside the assembly?

Command Line:
svcutil /noconfig /namespace:*,{NameSpace}.Automation.Runtime.Notifications.Proxy "wsdl\service\NotificationService{NameSpace}.Automation.Runtime.Notifications.wsdl" "wsdl\service\NotificationService{NameSpace}.Automation.Runtime.Notifications.xsd" "wsdl\service\NotificationService{NameSpace}.BusinessEntities.xsd" "wsdl\service\NotificationService{NameSpace}.BusinessEntities.Queue.xsd" "wsdl\service\NotificationService{NameSpace}.Diagnostics.xsd" "wsdl\service\NotificationService\schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd"  /r:"{NameSpace}.dll" /r:"{NameSpace}.Notifications.dll" /r:"{NameSpace}.Diagnostics.dll" /r:"{NameSpace}.BusinessEntities.Core.dll" /r:"{NameSpace}.BusinessEntities.Workflow.dll"* /excludeType:"{NameSpace}.Automation.Runtime.Notifications.Proxy.INotificationService"*  /ct:"{NameSpace}.Diagnostics.ErrorMessageCollection"   /o:E:\NotificationService.Proxy.cs /language:C#

Comment: Yes it should. Could you include the full command line (how you invoke svcutil)?

Comment: Thank you. I added the full command line. The {NameSpace} is just a place holder here.